# List Scheduled Task triggered at startup and logon c#

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, startup, winlogon

I am using http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx library to list task which are triggered at log on or startup

```
ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks();

            foreach (string taskName in st.GetTaskNames())
            {
                using (Task task = st.OpenTask(taskName))
                {

                        listBox1.Items.Add(taskName);

                }
            }
```

What condition shall I use to list only startup or logon tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enumerate the `Triggers` for each `task` and either do something with the task, store it for later, or store the name in a list of your filtered `Task` object names. Your selection process is to check if `Trigger` is either a `OnLogonTrigger` or a `OnSystemStartTrigger` then you can select that task into your final List.

e.g.

```
List<string> startupAndLogonTasks = new List<string>();
foreach (string taskName in st.GetTaskNames()) {
    using (Task task = st.OpenTask(taskName)) {
        if (task != null) {
            foreach (Trigger tr in task.Triggers) {
                if (tr is OnSystemStartTrigger || tr is OnLogonTrigger) {
                    //  Do something, such as log the name, or store the task for later
                    startupAndLogonTasks.Add(task.Name);
                    //  break out and move to the next task
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if you want tasks that only have the logon or startup type, then also check you only have 1 trigger in the `Triggers` collection.

Comment: I have a problem. The problem is this only work in xp. This code doesnt work in 7. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @grvpanchal. I don't think that the code project library works in 7 as it uses the Task Scheduler 1.0 API which was deprecated - ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)). You might need a new question about accessing tasks in Win 7.

Comment: @grvpanchal. "based on work the originator started in January 2002 with the 1.0 library that is currently hosted on CodeProject.", "single assembly wrapper for the 1.0 and 2.0 versions of Task Scheduler" - that looks ideal for you.